# Simulating mouse events and keyboard events c++ linux

Tags: c++, mouseevent

I need to simulate some mouse events and keyboard events for my project and having trouble finding much information about the same.

I tried out the original X11 code for simulating mouse which I got from the stackoverflow post, it seems to work fine but I'm not able to understand the code:

```
void mouseClick(int button)
{
   Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

   XEvent event;

   if(display == NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'apertura del Display !!!\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   memset(&event, 0x00, sizeof(event));

   event.type = ButtonPress;
   event.xbutton.button = button;
   event.xbutton.same_screen = True;

   XQueryPointer(display, RootWindow(display, DefaultScreen(display)), &event.xbutton.root, &event.xbutton.window, &event.xbutton.x_root, &event.xbutton.y_root, &event.xbutton.x, &event.xbutton.y, &event.xbutton.state);

   event.xbutton.subwindow = event.xbutton.window;

   while(event.xbutton.subwindow)
   {
      event.xbutton.window = event.xbutton.subwindow;

      XQueryPointer(display, event.xbutton.window, &event.xbutton.root, &event.xbutton.subwindow, &event.xbutton.x_root, &event.xbutton.y_root, &event.xbutton.x, &event.xbutton.y, &event.xbutton.state);
   }

   if(XSendEvent(display, PointerWindow, True, 0xfff, &event) == 0) fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");

   XFlush(display);

   usleep(100000);

   event.type = ButtonRelease;
   event.xbutton.state = 0x100;

   if(XSendEvent(display, PointerWindow, True, 0xfff, &event) == 0) fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");

   XFlush(display);

   XCloseDisplay(display);
}
```

so I wanted to ask if there were any simpler abstractions over the xlib library without going through all these as i even need to simulate keyboard actions which could be used with g++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) is a command line interface that I've used before and it's available in the Fedora repos.

There is also the related [libxdo](http://www.semicomplete.com/files/xdotool/docs/) that seems like it would be a more direct aid.  For example

[`xdo_mousemove     (const xdo_t * xdo, int x, int y, int screen)`](http://www.semicomplete.com/files/xdotool/docs/html/xdo_8h.html#a80693b1fa003dd7358a04f9e1a518ad9)

Answer (score 0):

XSendEvent doesn't work because many applications discard fake keyboard events by XSendEvent.

Best Way to simulate keyboard events is using XTestFakeKeyEvent api.

Following code will simulate F5 Key press event.

```
XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_F5), True, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_F5), False, 0);
```