# How to simulate press a key in linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, keypress

How to simulate press a key in linux kernel module?
I saw keybdev.c, but in my case I cant compile it `

> error: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_scancode’

Maybe it's obsolete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulating mouse events and keyboard events c++ linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041511/simulating-mouse-events-and-keyboard-events-c-linux)

Comment: It's not kernel module, your link is user space code as I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the kernel, keyboards can call [input_report_key](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.9/source/include/linux/input.h#L423) which generates a keyboard event.  The USB keyboard driver in /drivers/hid/usbhid/usbkbd.c is a good example of code to do both keyboard input and LED output.